# OleDbDataAdapter.Fill() The provider could not determine the Object value

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledbdataadapter

I am using C# .NET to talk to a (.mdb) MS Access Database file in a Windows Forms project.

I formerly displayed [date] as is in the dataGridView, but the client requested military date (YYYY-MM-DD) format.

Code:

```
    public void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string cmd = "SELECT TOP 1 [vial], [experiment], [field_vial], [host_or_trap], [capture->storage], [fungus], [locality], [county], [province], [Country], ( CStr(year([date])) & CStr(month([date])) & CStr(day([date])) ), [VIAL_note], [collector/museum], ( CStr(year([date collected])) & CStr(month([date collected])) & CStr(day([date collected])) ), [Field1] FROM [COLLECTIONS] WHERE vial LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
        OleDbCommand vialsearch = new OleDbCommand(cmd, this.thefile.dbo);
        OleDbDataAdapter vialadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(vialsearch);
        DataSet vials = new DataSet();
        vialadapter.Fill(vials, "INIT");
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = vials.Tables["INIT"];
        vialadapter.Dispose();
    }
```

When using Microsoft Jet OLEDB 4.0, the error message changes 'object' to 'string' -- all other wording thrown is the exact same. Currently using Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0.

What to do?

Comment: You can format the display however you'd like in the DGV without all that hokey-pokey.  The problem with doing it in SQL is that it is no longer a date and the DGV may noy see it as such and a DataAdapter may not apply changes

Comment: Indeed. Keep and pass date values whenever you can, and apply the format for display only.